# Is there a way to restrict the type of an object to the same of another one when using discriminated unions?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, static-typing

I have two classes:

```
interface Num {
    v: number, 
    type: 'num'
}

interface Sum {
    left: Expr, 
    right: Expr,
    type: 'sum'
}
```

and a type:

```
type Expr = Sum | Num;
```

I want to check if two `Expr` are equal, but with a standalone function (as opposed to an object oriented approach).

I would like to write something like:

```
function isEqual(e1: Expr, e2: Expr): boolean {
    if (e1.type !== e2.type) return false;
    switch(e1.type) {
        case 'num': return e1.v === e2.v;
        case 'sum': return isEqual(e1.left, e2.left) && isEqual(e1.right, e2.right);
    }
}
```

This is not possible because inside the switch the function doesn't know the type of `e2`.

I would need to write is like this:

```
function isEqual(e1: Expr, e2: Expr): boolean {
    if (e1.type !== e2.type) return false;
    switch(e1.type) {
        case 'num': return e1.v === (e2 as Num).v;
        case 'sum': return isEqual(e1.left, (e2 as Sum).left) && isEqual(e1.right, (e2 as Sum).right);
    }
}
```

that is quite messy.

Is there a way to make the compiler infer the the types of `e1` and `e2` in the `isEqual` function (after the initial check) must be equal, or at least have a common supertype without any explicit casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the type assertion is probably the only way to get what you want with a minimum of effort, sorry.

I just want to add onto this question that the issue seems to be that a pair of discriminated unions is not considered by the compiler to be a discriminated union itself.  Logically it is, where the discriminant is now the product of the discriminants of the two union types (that is, the set of all pairs of discriminants; in your case that would be {`["num","num"]`, `["num","sum"]`, `["sum","num"]`, and `["sum","sum"]`}), but the compiler does not go through such an analysis.  I assume it would be too expensive for the compiler to check such things, since detecting when discriminated unions are being used in concert like that would take some time which would usually be wasted.

You can sort of force the compiler to do this by synthesizing your own discriminated union out of the pair of discriminated unions, where you give an explicit mapping from each element of the product-of-disciminants to a new disciminant.  Here's the hoop-jumping code:

```
type DiscriminatedUnionPair<
  U, K extends keyof U,
  V, L extends keyof V,
  M extends Record<keyof M, readonly [U[K], V[L]]>> = {
    [P in keyof M]: {
      kind: P,
      first: Extract<U, Record<K, M[P][0]>>,
      second: Extract<V, Record<L, M[P][1]>>
    }
  }[keyof M];

function discriminatedUnionPair<U, K extends keyof U,
  V, L extends keyof V,
  M extends Record<keyof M, readonly [U[K], V[L]]>
>(
  firstUnion: U,
  firstDiscriminantKey: K,
  secondUnion: V,
  secondDiscriminantKey: L,
  disciminantMapping: M
): DiscriminatedUnionPair<U, K, V, L, M> {
  const p = (Object.keys(disciminantMapping) as Array<keyof M>).find(p =>
    disciminantMapping[p][0] === firstUnion[firstDiscriminantKey] &&
    disciminantMapping[p][1] === secondUnion[secondDiscriminantKey]
  );
  if (typeof p === "undefined") throw new Error("WHAT, MAPPING IS BAD");
  return { kind: p, first: firstUnion, second: secondUnion } as any;
}
```

That code could be shoved away in a library somewhere.  Then you could implement `isEqual()` like this with no errors:

```
function isEqual(e1: Expr, e2: Expr): boolean {
  const m = {
    sumsum: ["sum", "sum"],
    sumnum: ["sum", "num"],
    numsum: ["num", "sum"],
    numnum: ["num", "num"]
  } as const;
  const e = discriminatedUnionPair(e1, "type", e2, "type", m)
  switch (e.kind) {
    case 'numsum': return false;
    case 'sumnum': return false;
    case 'numnum': return e.first.v === e.second.v;
    case 'sumsum': return isEqual(e.first.left, e.second.left) &&
      isEqual(e.first.right, e.second.right);
  }
}
```

The important line is the call to `discriminatedUnionPair(e1, "type", e2, "type", m)`, which produces a new element of type `{kind: 'sumsum', first: Sum, second: Sum} | {kind: 'sumnum', first: Sum, second: Num} | {kind: 'numsum', first: Num, second: Sum} | {kind: 'numnum', first: Num, second: Num}` which TypeScript *does* recognize as a discriminated union in the way you expect, and the code behaves the way you want:

```
const n1: Num = { type: "num", v: 1 }
const n2: Num = { type: "num", v: 2 }
const s1: Sum = { type: "sum", left: n1, right: n2 }
const s2: Sum = { type: "sum", left: n2, right: n1 }

console.log(isEqual(n1, n1)); // true
console.log(isEqual(n1, n2)); // false
console.log(isEqual(n1, s1)); // false
console.log(isEqual(s2, n2)); // false
console.log(isEqual(s1, s2)); // false
console.log(isEqual(s2, s2)); // true
```

It's likely not worth it, of course, since you're forcing a new discriminated union to exist at runtime which only has relevance at compile time.  And you are manually enumerating all possible discriminant pairs, which could get old fast.  But I just wanted to show what is possible.

[‍‍](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-ICZGWwKI3Jen1k8WSmUOMCtDpBQLBfHABkOUsqzPksSuKAAMnrqQzXKz-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-ilqqj7jKW9BLpZE84GAJAD2tCA3QyOLUiQUNoGEjbROSRKEJOWjFL6aDTTh0y+pEwTkbg1GoHRzGYZxhHposwmkpOCHSxdFii2CCHh0ZrGoFhvpccRgmYKJ5LEDygqivpgpXWUiRgAql02cl4Bg0bVJZxy-LCuKhNxZdHS9JltmdYV6Dlgom6sFKlz5K6nzjOSHbFvYNioFmQiGFN6qLc60JrcgW2zsdyqXZuhBzYcq1kP423hvYeX2PemC4F01SsAD5Yg-d0OrYj9co6gGPz0q9gDdjl3XYoBAmohxSyGlZEhbVoqzfYM2FWnKAAHo258lA9ggUusHL5SXSrmu65F5FG-zlvNnbzvSd7s0K6H6va9VseJ+DqeZ5Jwq+j7gfK+X0f1YQAvJ9bjvt4x+ey8X4eV+F4+45PzeL7nvfb8P1fj9P5-z874Bu4QCAA)

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This is ugly, but it's really a beautiful kind of ugly! Thank you for this.

Comment: I can't help but wondering why don't TS just allow user to write "typetime" code (as op to runtime code), so we don't have to squeeze everything into a single expression

Answer (score 1):

Narrowing down discriminated union type is still quite stupid. But yeah there is a way, just that you probably won't like it.

```
function isEqual(e1: Expr, e2: Expr): boolean {
    if (e1.type !== e2.type) return false;
    const t1 = e1.type
    const t2 = e2.type
    switch(e1.type) {
        case 'num': return e1.type === e2.type && e1.v === e2.v;
        case 'sum': return e1.type === e2.type && isEqual(e1.left, e2.left) && isEqual(e1.right, e2.right);
    }
}
```

To make it slightly better, use a custom type guard

```
const s = function isSameType<T>(e1: T, e2: any): e2 is typeof e1 {
    return true
}

// then replace `e1.type === e2.type` with `s(e1, e2)`
// ...
    case 'num': return s(e1, e2) && e1.v === e2.v;
```

---

I'd briefly explain the reason behind.

You have 2 conditions here, obvious to human that both can do type narrowing in runtime.

```
/* PSEUDO CODE */
e1.type !== e2.type => (typeof e1 == typeof e2)
case 'num' => (typeof e1 == Num)

// we as human can tell:
(typeof e1 == typeof e2) & (typeof e1 == Num)
=> typeof e2 == Num

// but TS still see `typeof e2 == Expr`
// not smart enough to make connection btw 2 inferences.
```

However if you put `case` before `===`, TS can tell

```
/* PSEUDO CODE */
case 'num' => (typeof e1 == Num)
e1.type === e2.type => (typeof e1 == typeof e2)
(typeof e1 == Num) & (typeof e1 == typeof e2)
=> typeof e2 == Num
```

Comment: That was the same exact thing that I've tried. It's a pity that the inference with discriminated unions is not powerful enough to handle this case.

Comment: @heapOverflow Yeah, like i said, you won't like it.